# How to execute this query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_M_Products_ForUpdate]
ON [dbo].[M_Products]
FOR UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @TableName AS VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @DatabaseName AS VARCHAR(50)

    SELECT @DatabaseName= dbo.LogDataBaseName()

    SET @TableName =  @DatabaseName + '.dbo.M_products_Log'

    DECLARE @Query AS VARCHAR(100)

    SET  @Query = ' INSERT INTO '+ @TableName + ' SELECT * FROM deleted '
    EXEC (@Query)
END
```

I'm getting error:

> Invalid Object Name Deleted

How to resolve this error?

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to achieve

Comment: deleted doesn't exists in your database, it is a table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you can use "special" tables named `inserted` and `deleted` in the triggers, you can't use these tables in other batches called from the trigger.

Execution of dynamic sql code is exactly another new batch, so `deleted` table is not accessible from there.

Possible solution: first insert all the data from `deleted` table into temporary table, and use this table. Temporary table will be accessible from nested batch calls.

So you can change your query to

```
select * into #temp_deleted from deleted
SET  @Query = ' INSERT INTO '+ @TableName + ' SELECT * FROM #temp_deleted '
EXEC (@Query)
```

Comment: Kormeyev Sir i dont want to make Temp Table any other Solution.

Comment: You can't access `deleted` table directly in dynamic sql executed from trigger, so you have to pass its values either in temporary table or using custom user-defined type and table vairable. The way I've suggested is easiest and most commonly used one.